# How to write general-purpose, type-safe higher-order functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example, suppose I'm writing a memoize function, which accepts a function and returns another function. I want to leverage TypeScript so that the output function is guaranteed to have the same type as the input function, even though I don't know the type of the input function in advance. Here's some example code:

```
function wrap(fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    return fn(...args);
  };
}

function repeat1(a: string, b: number): string {
  return a.repeat(b);
}

const repeat2 = wrap(repeat1);
```

Unfortunately, `repeat2` resolves to the type `(...args: any[]) => any`. I can't seem to find a way to express the `wrap` function in such a way that propagates the input type to the output type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use generics and [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897)

```
function wrap<A extends any[], R>(fn: (...a: A) => R) {
  return function(...args: A) {
    return fn(...args);
  };
}

function repeat1(a: string, b: number): string {
  return a.repeat(b);
}

const repeat2 = wrap(repeat1); // inferred to const repeat2: (a: string, b: number) => string
```

The above version does not work for generic functions. We can create a version that preserves generic function arguments if we forgo any implementation type safety (this is an acceptable trade-off as we get better call site safety which is more important)

```
function wrap<T extends Function>(fn: T): T {
    return function(...args: any[]) :any {
        return fn(...args);
    } as any;
}

wrap(<T>(x: T): T => x)
```

Comment: It works for the above case, but this: `wrap(<T>(x: T): T => x)` "forgets" the input type and resolves to `(...args: any[]) => any`. (Which I see mentioned in the caveats)

Comment: @greim Added a version that plays better with generics

Comment: This works, though it seems kind of hacky. Is it safe to say that TypeScript doesn't yet support fully generic functional programming?

Comment: @greim I guess the answer is not 100%. You can get it to work 100% for the call site, but the implementation will require some type assertions. The good news is implementations are written once and used many time so it's better than nothing :)